# Divergence of the gradient of f

Tags: real-analysis, divergence-operator

I just learned about the Laplacian, curl and divergence operators and frowned confusingly after stumbling on this notation: $ \bigtriangleup f(x) = ( (\nabla \cdot \nabla )f )(x) 
 = \nabla \cdot (\nabla f) (x)$. The thing is, when I try to expand the second term I get:
$( (\nabla \cdot \nabla )f )(x) = ((\partial^{2}_{xx} + \partial^{2}_{yy} + \partial^{2}_{zz}) f ) (x)$. The RHS clearly shows we're dealing with a scalar and if we multiply $ f $ with the operators we'd end up with the definition of the Laplacian, which is fine. Now, I'm really wondering if this$(\partial^{2}_{xx} + \partial^{2}_{yy} + \partial^{2}_{zz})$ is legit. Maybe it's just physics notation, which isn't super pedantic and rigourous, or maybe I just got it all wrong. I'd appreciate it if soemone could explain where I messed up. Thanks !

Comment: Usually, one should write $\partial^2_x$ or $\partial^2_{xx}$, but not $\partial^2_{x^2}$, which might be thought of as the derivation with respect to $x^2$ (the square of $x$). Except that, $\Delta = \partial^2_x+\partial^2_y+\partial^2_z$ is the usual definition of the Laplacian, and is indeed the same as $\nabla\cdot\nabla$ ... at least when taking derivatives in $\Bbb R^3$ ... what is really your problem/questions here?

Comment: Your title is incorrect. It's the divergence of the gradient of $f$. What you wrote actually makes no sense.

Comment: @TedShifrin I edited the question to take into account your comments, but the original title was actually the center of the question. If you look at this form $ ∇⋅(∇)() $, then yes, we're taking the "divergence of the gradient of $f$". My question is about this notation $ ((∇⋅∇)) $, which I'm (incorrectly) reading as the "divergence of the divergence of $f$". I hope I made my question more clear...